# I need help declaring parameters in simple C code

Tags: c, parameters

I wrote a very simple C program; It's *main.c* *constants.c* and *constants.h*

Here is *main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "constants.h"

int main(){
printf("a=%f\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

Here's *constants.c*

```
#include "constants.h"
float a = 1.0;
float b = 3.0;
float c = a + b;
```

here is *constants.h*

```
extern float a;
extern float b;
extern float c;
```

After I try to compile it with gcc I get the following error:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
float c = a + b;
```

I read in the Internet the reasons why I get the message but I couldn't find any practical solution to it; my goal is to get `c = a + b` by keeping the structure of the code (the 3 files); can anyone tell what I should do in order to achieve my goal?

I forgot to mention an important thing: I must not use `#define` as a possible solution

Comment: Can you make a function in *constants.c*? Maybe call it something like `initialize_globals()`?

Comment: yes I see what you mean... that actually could be a possible solution

Comment: @pmg could you give an example of your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `float c` is in global scope and in global scope, you cannot use an expression like `a + b` for initalization. You need to have a function which will do the job explicitly.

---

EDIT:

Just for example, without using any function, you can do something like this

```
#define A 1.0
#define B 3.0
#define C (A+B)

float a = A;
float b = B;
float c = C;
```

Comment: could you give an example of your answer please? I have tried what you said but I'm stuck

Comment: @dingodile Sure !! define `float c` and do not initalize. Write another function `void init_var(float initval){c = initval};` and call the function from your `main()` like `init_var(a+b);`. That's one way of achieving the same.

Comment: mmm...  I see what you mean ... but I had in mind a different goal; Is there a way instead of defining the function inside of the constant.c file? My idea is to keep all the parameters in the same file

Comment: @dingodile See, you cannot use an expression containing variables like `a + b` to initialize another global. Either you've to use a function, or a `constant expression` or `string literal`.

Comment: Would you be so kind to post an answer where you show how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
#define A 1.0
#define B 3.0

float a = A;
float b = B;
float c = A+B;
```

Comment: I actually thought about that but I must not use# define as a possible solution

Comment: Always funny how these homework questions "aren't allowed" this and that as an afterthought. I was about to post the very same answer. Upvoted.

Comment: I'd put  `1.0` and `3.0` in parenthesis: `#define A (1.0)`

Comment: It seems a very reasonable solution to me. Note that since the define are in constants.c, they won't be visible elsewhere.

Comment: Why don't you give any kind of explanation?

Comment: "I need to do X. The C language provides feature Y precisely for doing X. Oh, BTW, I can't use feature Y."  Well, then don't use langauge C, and don't bother us to solve problems that are already solved.

Comment: The reason why I cannot use #define is because I must specify that I am using floats or integers... so I would like to have them all specified

Comment: This answer does precisely that. All variables have a type, and retain that type after being initialized (with initializers, that, as you point out, don't have a type). I don't see the problem.

Comment: `a`, `b` and `c` are all declared as `float`. This answer does exactly what you want, `#define` simply lets the pre-processor do the work of initialising their values.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker ok... i see your point and i'm gonna try that too... but do you think there's a way to do it like I said?

Comment: If you insist, you could use `#define A ((float)3.0)` , but that really accomplishes nothing but wasting a little time.

Comment: @ Weather Vane ok but let's say I need to define an integer; how does the compiler know the difference then?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker *"initializers don't have a type"* simply isn't true. See a recent discussion  about the value `'z'` which is of type `int`.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker Thanks!! I'm gonna try it now

Comment: @weather, yes, defines don't have a type, they're just text. Initializers might be typed expressions.

Comment: I actually tried what you suggest: but if i define 2 integers like this: #define a ((int)1)  and #define b ((int)2) the compiler allows me to define a float like this:  float c = a+b; I don't think that should be allowed

Comment: The pre-processor doesn't *care* what you think. It just substitutes the text. The compiler then adds the integer values, converts them to the correct type and a `printf()` gives the answer `3.000000`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use gcc's `__attribute__` extension:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "constants.h"

int main(void) {
    // initilize_globals(); // function with __attribute__ ((constructor))
    printf("a = %f\n", a);
    printf("b = %f\n", b);
    printf("c = %f\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

constants.c

```
#include "constants.h"
float a = 1.0;
float b = 3.0;
float c;
// __attribute__ ((constructor)) is a gcc extension
__attribute__ ((constructor)) void initialize_globals(void) {
    // you can assign a and b here instead of above
    c = a + b;
}
```

constants.h

```
extern float a;
extern float b;
extern float c;
// void initialize_globals(void);
```

Comment: Ok like this works; but what I want to do the same think without touching the main.c file? Is there a way just to modify only the constant.c and constant.h?

Comment: with gcc you can use *__attribute__* ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html ). I tried it on my computer and it worked. Just added `__attribute__ ((constructor))` before the function definition in *constants.c* and removed the call in *main.c*. Answer edited